# Описание к картинке при наведении

Tags: css3, html5, вёрстка, анимация

Подскажите как, к данным карточкам можно добавить анимацию (только на `css`).
Что бы при наведении появлялся блок, в котором есть название картинки и описание картинки.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.gallery {
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  display: flex;
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.gallery_item_img:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.gallery_item_img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <div class="gallery_item">
    <img class="gallery_item_img" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random" />
  </div>
  <div class="gallery_item">
    <img class="gallery_item_img" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random" />
  </div>
  <div class="gallery_item">
    <img class="gallery_item_img" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну во-первых вы hover привязали к контейнеру, подсказка будет всплывать на весь контейнер.
Нужно так:

```css
.gallery {
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  display: flex;
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.gallery_item_img:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.gallery_item_img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <div class="gallery_item">
    <img class="gallery_item_img" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random" />
  </div>
  <div class="gallery_item">
    <img class="gallery_item_img" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random" />
  </div>
  <div class="gallery_item">
    <img class="gallery_item_img" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Во-вторых вот:

```css
.gallery_item {
position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.text {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  color: #fff;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 10px 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(5,13,156,.55);
}
.gallery_item:hover .text {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 0.6s;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <div class="gallery_item">
    <img class="gallery_item_img" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random" />
    <div class = "text">Суматранский тигр</div>
  </div>
  <div class="gallery_item">
    <img class="gallery_item_img" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random" />
    <div class = "text">Суматранский тигр</div>
  </div>
  <div class="gallery_item">
    <img class="gallery_item_img" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random" />
    <div class = "text">Суматранский тигр</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Первое исправил.
А во-вторых?)

Comment: Во-вторых ниже первого))